# How can I change a default global key used in my app in a windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an app with a global key by default and it works perfectly, but I want when somebody else use my app, use their desired global key by changing it in setting form in my app.

There are **3 checkboxes, one for ctrl, alt and shift, and one combobox from A to Z and a button for saving the new global key** and can save it for future using, but I don't know how to do it.

[image: a picture of my form]

I'm using visual studio 2013, Windows Forms and I want the setting be saved for loading it after closing and opening the app again.

How can I create and save this setting so I can use even after closing the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this to build your keys object:

```
Keys keys = Keys.None;

if (chkControl.Checked)
    keys |= Keys.Control;

if (chkShift.Checked)
    keys |= Keys.Shift;

if (chkAlt.Checked)
    keys |= Keys.Alt;

Keys selectedKey;

Enum.TryParse(cbSelectedKey.SelectedValue.ToString(), out selectedKey);

keys |= selectedKey;
```

And then save the value in the project settings for example:

[image: project settings]

Right click your project, go to properties then settings. Add a new field of type `int`.

And then you can save it: (`using YourPrjName.Properties;`)

```
// Shortcut is the name of the property I created.
Settings.Default.Shortcut = (int)keys;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

To retrieve the value when it is already saved just access:

```
var keys = (Keys)Settings.Default.Shortcut;
```

Some resources to understand better each step described here:

- [Application Settings Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k4s6c3a0.aspx)

  - [How to Create Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wabtadw6.aspx)
- [Keys Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx)

  - [Flags Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: sorry I'm new in C#, can you explain more or clearer?

Comment: I have a problem with this line:Enum.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), out selectedKey); the debugger get the tray parse problem? whay?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're asking for help with allowing your end-users to modify the keyboard settings of your application. There's a few possible ways you could do this:

1. Keep an internal reference to the saved key in the application settings.
2. Have your application parse its configuration data from an external configuration file (e.g. a .txt/.xml/etc.). Overwrite this configuration file with the new settings each time the user changes and saves their configuration. 
   for .txt: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx 
   for .xml: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28VS.95%29.aspx
3. Create a class to encapsulate the behavior which implements Serializable. Load an instance of this at launch and save a new instance of this class when the user modifies the configuration.
   This can get you started with the process of saving the objects: http://tech.pro/tutorial/618/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file

Comment: No, my app don't parse its configuration data from a file, i wantjust the user can use her desired global key.

Comment: You should be more specific - first off, are you using Windows Forms or WPF? Secondly, when you say "future using," do you mean for the remainder of the application's runtime, or do you intend for that selection to persist after the application is closed and reopened?

Comment: it's a windows form and i want it be saved and loaded again after closing and opening the app again

Comment: Then you'll need to serialize your data in some sense, as I stated above. If you don't want to use an external file, you could use a local SQL table, but I think that'd be overkill.

Comment: I think it doesn't need to be serialized,because i want just know the user desire global key and set it instead of the default app global key in the setting form just like the picture added to my question.